# Android authentication via webview

Tags: android, authentication, android-webview

I'm sorry for this as I am very Green at this Android Development, and I maybe beating a dead horse here-
A software tjat we use has a mobile version, but it's a mobile website, I am trying to build this into a standalone web-app using webview.

The app will get me to the login screen, but when I attempt to login the the pop-up showing its logging in, and in my webview, it is sticking there. It doesn't move past this point.
In the default browser it works fine.

Can you please assist me in what I need to do to get pass this in the most simple terms? ;-) Thank you!

```
package com.giantflyingsaucer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://URL.USED.FOR/WEBAPP");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by using
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your login is trying to make use of some web plugin. Try adding one or both of these:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! ill give this a try. where exactally is the best place to add the code.

Comment: On the two lines of code I get-

PluginState cannot be resolved or is not a field

mWebView cannot be resolved

Comment: did you fix your imports so that it would get imported?